# Problema concatenando un string con entero

Tags: c++, string

Tengo una lista que contiene 2 strings(fecha y nombre) y un entero, necesito que se muestre en pantalla de la siguiente forma : **FECHA NOMBRE NUMERO**.

El problema es que cuanto trato de hacer:

```
cout<<fecha<<"-"<<nombre<<"-"<<to_string(numero)<<'\n';
```

La hora elimina parte de la fecha, quedando en algo como (siendo numero=10, fecha ="02/03/2020" y nombre "Jose luis")

```
-10 /2020 -Jose Luis
```

La hora elimina parcialmente la fecha.

Haciendo muchas pruebas me di cuenta de lo siguiente:

Si hago cout separados por una linea queda asi:

```
10
02/03/2020
Jose Luis
```

Si hago cout separados pero sin un salto de linea para que todo se imprima en la misma linea y  separados por un char de '-' queda asi:

```
-1003/2020-Jose Luis
```

Casi toda combinacion que he tratado de hacer termina como la anterior, pero lo que me he podido dar cuenta es que:

**Fecha+nombre imprime bien.**

**Fecha + hora imprime bien.**

**Nombre + hora** hace que la hora se posicione de primero y elimine 4 caracteres del nombre
ejemp 15 Luis

He tratado de usar **append** con un str vacio e ir añadiendo progresivamente pero por algún motivo **hora_string=to_string(hora_entero)** siempre se posiciona de primero.
Ejemplo de la secuencia con un string vacio:

```
""
"Fecha"  //append fecha
"Fecha nombre" //append nombre
"xx cha nombre" //apend hora(xx)
```

**Ejem grafico:**

```
02/03/2020 
02/03/2020 Pepe Luis
10 03/2020 Pepe Luis
```

No entiendo por que la hora se va de primero y elimina si debería irse agregando al final como otros strings.

**Pero si es al revés funciona**

```
""
"hora"
"hora fecha"
"hora fecha nombre"
```

**Ejemplo grafico**

```
10 
10 02/03/2020 
10 02/03/2020 Pepe Luis
```

**Pero si cambio el orden de fecha y nombre queda asi**

```
"hora"
"hora nombre"
"fecha bre"
```

**Ejemplo grafico**

```
10 
10 Crist Gonzalez
02/03/2020 nzalez
```

Trate de hacer cout a la hora sin convertirla a string y no puedo usar char porque hay numeros de mas de 1 digito.

No entiendo por que esto causa tanto problema si en teoria es algo sencillo y creo que precisamente por eso me encuentro un poco frustrado. Acudo aca con la esperanza de que me puedan ayudar a decifrar cual es el problema y a aprender un poco más sobre c++

No estoy usando objetos y la naturaleza de todo el proyecto que me encuentro realizado impide que usemos otro elemento diferente a listas. Personalmente no creo que la lista tenga algo que ver, los tipos de datos son los comentados, 2 string y un int, trate de usar funciones diferentes y unirlas y nada. Si tienen alguna idea por favor ayudenme. Y gracias si llegaste hasta acá

**Edit**:

**Codigo**

```
struct nodo{
    int ID;
    string nombre;
    string fecha;
    int hora;
    nodo *sig;
};
typedef struct nodo_cita *nodo_apuntador; 


void mostrarVariasFechasCitas (nodo_apuntador lista )
{
    nodo_aputador prueba=lista;
    string completo="";
    string fecha=fechaActual();  //Devuelve un string con la fecha
        while (prueba!=NULL)
        {
            if(fecha==prueba->fecha){
                      
                 //todas las pruebas que mencione arriba.
                cout<<prueba->fecha<<"-"<<prueba->nombre<<"-"<<prueba->hora<<endl;


            }

            prueba=prueba->sig;
        }
        
    
}
```

Esto me devuelve:

**-1508/2020-Juan Gonzalez**

Cuando fecha es 10/08/2020 y la hora es 15

**EDIT 2**

Aca muestro el comportamiento de fechaActual. En el resto del programa me ha funcionado perfectamente para otras cosas. No creo que sea la del problema, pero lo que sea necesario para descartar.

```
string fechaActual(){
    int dia,mes,anio;
    string fecha_texto;
    anio=2020;
    cout<<"Dia:"<<endl;
    cin>>dia;
    cou<<"Mes:"<<endl;
    cin>>mes;
    fecha_texto=to_string(dia)+"/"+to_string(mes)+"/"+to_string(anio);
    return fecha_texto
}
```

Comment: @eferion Listo, no pensé que fuera muy necesario porque creí que sería algo simple con el manejo de output. Tuve que cambiar algunas cosas del codigo para mostrarlo y que se entendiera mejor pero espero pueda ilustrar un poco

Comment: Nos faltaría conocer los valores que las variables de la estructura `lista`

Comment: Vale, el código tiene alguna que otra inconsistencia... declaras `struct nodo` y después usas `struct nodo_cita`... Tienes que intentar presentar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema. Con códigos incompletos va a estar complicado darte una respuesta

Comment: @eferion Disculpa es mi primera pregunta acá y trato de no copiar todo porque no quiero que sea largo, tengo el código en github,  No se si se permite, pero acá lo dejaria supongo [https://github.com/isaac152/Proyecto_Alg2] El problema estaria concretamente en pruebacita.h

Comment: No se van a responder preguntas basadas en repositorios... si ese repositorio desaparece en el futuro la pregunta dejará de tener sentido. Lo que tienes que intentar es elaborar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema. Mínimo quiere decir con el mínimo código imprescindible y completo se refiere a que el código debe compilar y ejecutarse